# Building NumPy array using values from another array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
index_info = np.matrix([[1, 1], [1, 2]])
value =  np.matrix([[0.5, 0.5]])
initial = np.zeros((3, 3))
```

How can I produce a matrix, final, which has the structure of `initial` with the elements specified by `value` at the locations specified by `index_info` WITHOUT a for loop? In this toy example, see below.

```
final =  np.matrix([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0.5, 0.5], [0, 0, 0]])
```

With a for loop, you can easily loop through all of the index's in index_info and value and use that to populate initial and form final. But is there a way to do so with vectorization (no for loop)?

Answer (score 2):

Convert `index_info` to a tuple and use it to assign:

```
>>> initial[(*index_info,)]=value
>>> initial
array([[0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.5, 0.5],
       [0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

Please note that use of the `matrix` class is discouraged. Use `ndarray` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with NumPy's [array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing):

```
>>> initial = np.zeros((3, 3))

>>> row = np.array([1, 1])
>>> col = np.array([1, 2])

>>> final = np.zeros_like(initial)
>>> final[row, col] = [0.5, 0.5]
>>> final
array([[0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.5, 0.5],
       [0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

This is similar to @PaulPanzer's answer, where he is unpacking `row` and `col` from `index_info` all in one step.  In other words:

```
row, col = (*index_info,)
```